# Resolve GIT Merge conflicts via command line programmatically?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am trying to clean up the branches in my repository programmatically from time to time just to maintain the hygiene and delete un-required branches.
Since my team is big with multiple developers working on various sub-modules, a new feature branch gets created every moment.
The GIT instance we are using doesn't have an option of deleting the branch as soon as it gets merged to the main branch.
So I am trying to write a Python script which can scan my repo for branches older than 3 months and no commits, identify them, merge them to a dummy repo named trash and then delete them.

When I try to do a "git merge ", it throws an error that there are multiple merge conflicts.
I have tried other options as :

1. git merge -X ours
2. git merge -X theirs

Comment: Why do you need to merge them, why not just delete?

Comment: @jt11 Didn't make sense to me either but I guess it's so that the commits will still be reachable so that they won't be GCed. In case of regrets.